# How to display Quote line items discount in Items to approve

Tags: opportunity, approval-process, quotelineitem, approval-history

I have a requirement to display discount in Items to approve,

Opportunity -------> Quote --------> Quote Line Item

Now, Opportunity have Approval history related list and **i need to display Quote line item Discount in this approval history**.

Is it possible ?
if so please suggest me the way please

Comment: Do you need to display each line and its discount, or just the overall discount for the Quote?

Comment: @DavidSchach Sorry i was slept last night. Yes, Each line with discount.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this?